# How to detect that site is hosted on WPEngine?

Tags: hosting, cookies

Is there anyway to detect that WordPress is hosted on WPEngine? The reason why I need to know it in their approach [to eliminate cookies](http://wpengine.com/support/cookies-and-php-sessions/). But my plugin relies on cookie and can't work without it. So I need to not run the plugin on WPEngine hosting. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you asked anyone at WPEngine? They seem like fairly reasonable guys and I'm sure would answer this question without a problem. Or just let them know your plugin doesn't work, and they'll add it to their list of plugins they don't allow and will automatically remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick look at wpengines headers it looks like there may be some info you can check.
Your best bet is to get access to an account and dump out `$_SERVER` to see what's in there. For example it looks like `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'WP Engine/4.0'`. or perhaps `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

As per the comments below it also seems the `wp-config.php` on wpengine defines some custom constants you could check, for example `WPE_APIKEY` , `WPE_ISP`.

Of course the problem is this can change at anytime outside your control.

#### Updated:

There is another workaround to figure out whether WPEngine is used. WPEngine uses its own MU plugin, which contains `WPE_API` class. By checking whether this class exists, we can say whether the plugin is hosted on WPEngine hosting or not.

```
if ( class_exists( 'WPE_API', false ) ) {
    // is WPEngine hosting
} else {
    // is not WPEngine hosting
}
```

Comment: WP Engine also sets some custom constants in their in their wp-config file but the same caveat goes. They could change at any time.

Comment: [Here's a sample](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/118901/revisions) of their wp-config.

Comment: Yes, looks like this is the only way to do it...

Comment: I asked them via twitter: https://twitter.com/wycks_s/status/390961973145255936